# Xcode 10 UI test failing for iOS 12 devices

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have recently update to Xcode 10 and have noticed some strange behaviour between UI tests run against iOS 11 or iOS 12 simulators.

If the run the following UI test code, everything works as expected on an IOS 11 device. I am using a check as to the device type as on iPhones it is a single table that is displayed in collapsed form as it is part of a UISplitViewController. However, on iPad there are two tables (master and detail), so the number of cells is greater in this case

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.isRunningOnIpad ? 7 : 4, app.tables.cells.count)
```

However as soon as I switch to the same device (iPhone 7), but running iOS 12.0, the assertion above fails saying that 7 is not equal to 4. Which suggests it is counting all the cells in the UISplitViewController, even though only one is shown (a change from iOS 11)

If break on that line and then print out the value of app.tables.cells.count in the debugger, it is correct (4). If I break on that line and then continue in the debugger, the test passes. If you add a sleep(1) in front of the assertion it passes.

To me this seems like a bug in the testing framework. I just tested the beta of Xcode 10.1 and the problem is still there. Has anyone else ran into this or has there been a change that I missed that would explain things?

Comment: Have you tried to apply some thread sleeping, I am also curious if they messed up the timing.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt. Had meant to try this and then got distracted. Yes, if you put a sleep(1) in front of the assertion, the test passes. I updated my question.

Comment: UITests have this sort of issues here and there all the time, including you switching apps and stuff like that. When this happens sleeping isn't a bad choice.

Comment: Agree, but it feels like this is happening a lot more then I ever saw before. I have 20+ tests that now fail and I would really prefer to not to have hack things. I filed a bug report with apple.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a simple example that demonstrated the problem to add to my bug report to apple. The behaviour is definitely different that iOS 11 and on a different machine the total number of failures changed, but maybe its more of a behaviour change rather than a bug. For me, the best way to solve this was to more actively use XCUIElement's waitForExistence(timeout:) method any time the view hierarchy was changing.